# Admin screens show error after fresh Kentico 10 upgrade

Tags: kentico

This one is a head scratcher. I'm testing upgrading from 8.2 to 11. On the 9.0 to 10.0 leg of the journey, I see this on every admin screen in version 10:

```
 [Error loading the layout]
 Could not load type 'CMS.PortalControls.CMSAbstractLayout'.
```

[image: this is what I see]

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMS.PortalControls.CMSAbstractLayout` moved to `CMS.PortalEngine.Web.UI.CMSAbstractLayout` in Kentico 10. The API changes were quite wide reaching.   Did you make sure that you team the code upgrade tool?. The release notes etc can be found on devnet. https://docs.kentico.com/k10/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-10

Comment: Thanks. It turns out my team had already created the patch for this, but I had to toggle deployment mode off during the upgrade, then on afterwards, for the patch to apply correctly.